# Scraping using CSS Selectors with ::before isn't displaying text

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrap `Monday, 9:30 AM` from [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/145599690533?) ebay listing, using scrapy.

From a scrapy shell `scrapy shell https://www.ebay.com/itm/145599690533?`:

```
>>> response.css('span.ux-timer__time-left::text')
[]
```

I've also tried copying the css path and xpath from Firefox Dev but they gave the same result.

I suspect the issue has something to do with the `::before` before the plaintext, but I know next to nothing about that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you aren't missing nothing. Your element selection is correct but getting none by scrapy shell because that value is populated by javaScript and scrapy can't mimic it.

Just example that your css selection is working using selenium with beautifulsoup:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
#chrome to stay open
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)

driver.get("https://www.ebay.com/itm/145599690533?")
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
date = soup.select_one('span.ux-timer__time-left').get_text()
print(date)
```

**Output:**

```
Monday, 08:30 PM
```

Comment: Thanks.  This should be sufficient for development, but won't scale well with millions of requests.  Any suggestions?

Comment: In that case, use API request with scrapy if data is available thus way. Thanks

Comment: I would, but unfortunately eBay only allows use of the Buy APIs in applications they have audited.  They only want consumer facing applications using their Buy API.